# jBPM Login Failed: Not Authorized: All of the pre-defined users dont work

Tags: drools, jbpm, kie-workbench

I am trying to use the Business-Central/Workbench module. Followed the instructions as provided in the `[Getting Started][1]` of jBPM. I tried with all the pre-defined logins. Nothing works.
It throws

[image]

I also tried to look into the `application-roles.properties` and `application-users.properties` files. Both seems to be empty (only comments).

The error is something like:

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-5) UT005023: Exception handling request to /business-central/rest/controller/server/sample-server: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/acl/Group
...
...
...
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.security.acl.Group from [Module "org.picketbox" from local module loader @2c07545f (finder: local module finder @e57b96d (roots: /Users/abcd/EclipseProjects/Drools_Workbench/jbpm-server-7.43.1.Final-dist/modules,/Users/abcd/EclipseProjects/Drools_Workbench/jbpm-server-7.43.1.Final-dist/modules/system/layers/base))]
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a dependency from your classpath. Have you tried adding it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the issue. It is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/acl/Group
```

This pointed to an incompatible JDK. I downgraded from JDK14 to JDK11.

Comment: Interesting.  I get a similar error on going up from JDK 1.8 to JDK 14.  I wonder if I need to rebuild - but most people using JBPM are not building from source!  (And JDK 11 should have been fine if you were using that all along)