# jBPM Unable to login Remotely

Tags: jboss, wildfly

We I very novices of jBPM. I installed JBoss jBPM 7.70 on Ubuntu 20.04 Linux server. I have installed Open Java 11.

After login, I modified the standalone.xml and the 127.0.0.1/Localhost to Linux host IP(0.0.0.0).

I created one user 'adminuser' with the same password

But when trying to login to the system getting '***Login failed: Not Authorized***'.
[image]

I tried

```
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64214744/jbpm-login-failed-not-authorized-all-of-the-pre-defined-users-dont-work

    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75193736/drools-workbench-with-jbpm-server-7-73-0-final-dist-file-from-jbpmn-org-site

    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58882250/cannot-start-jbpm-on-http-localhost8080-business-central

    https://www.baeldung.com/wildfly-remote-access
```

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After dedicating two days to the task, I successfully discovered the solution to the issue I was facing. The problem was related to the standalone.xml file. Initially, when I ran the server using the command

```
./standalone.sh
```

The application used the **standalone.xml** configuration, but there seemed to be an issue with this specific file.

However, I made progress when I tried running the application using the command

```
./standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml
```

By using this alternate configuration file, I was delighted to find that I could now successfully log in with both the users **adminuser/adminuser** and **wbadmin/wbadmin**

Thanks to all